# How to compare struct fields to variables in C?

Tags: c, struct

This is part of a deletion function in a linked list program. I'm trying to compare the fields of the current struct node to fields read in by the user for searching. I know my node referencing works as I can print out current fields on their own, but my comparisons in the if statement to the variables does not. How can I compare the fields of current to the user data? Thanks

```
int deleteEmployee(void)
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
    char gender[2];
    int age;
    char position[MAX_JOB_LENGTH];
    int placeInList = 0;

    Employee *current = employeeListHead;
    Employee *previous = employeeListHead;

    printf("Enter details of employee to delete: \n");
    printf("Name: \n");   
    scanf(" %100[^\n]s", name); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Gender: \n");
    scanf(" %1s", gender); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Age: \n");
    scanf(" %d", &age); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    printf("Title: \n");
    scanf(" %100[^\n]s", position); 
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");

    //while elements in list to search
    while(current != NULL)
    {
```

This Specifically

```
        //handling a match on each iteration
        if (current->name == name && current->gender == gender && current->age == age && current->position == position)
        {
            printf("\nIs this the emplyee you'd like to delete? Please confirm (Y/N) %s %s %d %s \n\n", name, gender, age, position);
            char choice;
            scanf(" %c", &choice);

            //if delete is confirmed
            if (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y')
            {   
                //if head of list
                if(current == employeeListHead)
                {
                    employeeListHead = current->next;
                    current = NULL;
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                //if tail
                else if(current->next == NULL)
                {   
                    //change previous nodes pointer
                    for (int i=0; current!=NULL && i < placeInList-1; i++)
                    {
                        previous->next = NULL;
                    }
                        
                    current = NULL;
                    
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                //if inside list
                else
                {
                    for (int i=0; current!=NULL && i < placeInList-1; i++)
                    {
                        previous->next = current->next;
                    }                    
                    current = NULL;
                    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                }
                 
            }//end if yes selected to delete

            //if delete is confirmed
            if (choice == 'N' || choice == 'n')
            {
                printf("You selected N. Returning to main menu.");
                EXIT_FAILURE;
            }//end if no selected to delete

        }//end if a match

        //iterate to next set of nodes
        current = current->next;
        previous = previous->next;
        placeInList++;

    }//end iterating through list
    

    printf("Employee not found in system.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

    
}
```

Comment: use `strcmp` to compare string in C, not `==`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings.  When you write `current->name == name`, your program is just comparing the location of two pointers.  (But you didn't show the definition of `name`, so it's hard to be sure.)

Try replacing all string comparisons with something like:

```
0 == strcmp(current->name, name)
```